# How to mock service in angularAMD with karma/jasmine?

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine, angular-amd

I have a project using AngularAMD/RequireJS/Karma/Jasmine, that I have the basic configuration all working, most unit tests run and pass successfully.

I cannot get a mocked service injected correctly using either angular.mock.module or angularAMD.value().

I have:

```
// service definition in services/MyService.js
define(['app'], 
       function(app) {
           app.factory('myService', [ '$document', function($document) {
               function add(html) {
                   $document.find('body').append(html);
               }
               return { add: add }; 
           }]);
       }
);


// test
define(['angularAMD', 'angular-mocks', 'app', 'services/MyService'],
       function(aamd, mocks, app) {
           describe('MyService', function() {
               var myBodyMock = {
                   append: function() {}
               };
               var myDocumentMock = {
                   find: function(sel) {
                       // this never gets called 
                       console.log('selector: ' + sel);
                       return myBodyMock; 
                   }
               }; 
               var svc;
               beforeEach(function() {
                   // try standard way to mock a service through ng-mock
                   mocks.module(function($provide) {
                       $provide.value('$document', myDocumentMock);
                   });
                   // hedge my bets - try overriding in aamd as well as ng-mock
                   aamd.value('$document', myDocumentMock);              
               });
               beforeEach(function() { 
                   aamd.inject(['myService', 
                               function(myService) {
                                   svc = myService;
                               }]);
               });
               it('should work', function() {
                   // use svc expecting it to have injected mock of $document.
                   spyOn(myDocumentMock, 'find').andCallThrough();
                   spyOn(myBodyMock, 'append');
                   svc.add('<p></p>');
                   expect(myDocumentMock.find).toHaveBeenCalledWith('body');
                   expect(myBockMock.append).toHaveBeenCalledWith('<p></p>');
               });
           });
       }
);
```

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong ? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: have a look at angularamd's git, there are some good test examples.

Answer (score 0):

Angular isn't asynchronous, I think is not a good ideia use both. If you're trying to reach to a good modularization method, okay, but use the RequireJS optimizer to build everything before you put this on your browser, and about the tests, I think you can just use RequireJS optimizer to build your modules before, it will let you free from "CommonJS environment even in tests".

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it'll be an issue with variable scopes, karma is very finicky about that. I think you should initialize your mock objects globally, then set them in the beforeEach.

The top line of my test files always looks something like:

var bodyMock, svcMock, foo, bar

Then in the beforeEach'es I set the values

Edit: Since bodyMock is only a scope variable, at the point where the tests are actually running and the browser is looking for an object 'bodyMock', it can't find anything.